# How can I import the csvsql to Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csvkit

I have successfuly installed  csvkit using conda install ...

[image]

However, when I try to import the libraries in Python 2.7 Spyder, I get error messages:

```
     import csvsql
     Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-5-303a60a6b1ac>", line 1, in <module>

     import csvsql

     ImportError: No module named csvsql

     import csvkit
     Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-7-ca8a99ae9834>", line 1, in <module>
      import csvkit

      ImportError: No module named csvkit
```

I looked at the documentation -- they describe the installation process but not how the library is loaded in Python.

Moreover, I had an analogous problem with httplib2.  I installed it successfuly but when I tried to import it in Spyder I received an analogous error message (No module named httplib2).

(I use Anaconda 3 and Spyder on Windows 11)

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the csvkit GitHub / issues forum.
The answer given was: You should use agate on which csvkit now relies for all its operations. See https://github.com/wireservice/agate.

I'm with you -- it would be wonderful to use csvkit as a command-line tool and a library, but it's authors don't see it that way. The full issue: https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/670

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I installed agate using pip as recommended.  However, when I tried to import it ("importa agade") in Spyder I got the "usual" error message ("No module named agade").  Moreover, assuming I import agade, what I should do to run csvsql code?  My end objective is to create a table in a database using a csv file and import that file in the database.  There is a post at Stckoverflow that has a similar example: "createdb test
csvsql --db postgresql:///test --table fy09 --insert examples/realdata/FY09_EDU_Recipients_by_State.csv"

Comment: @im7: typo? You wrote "agade", but instead it should be "agate".